# Error en la interfaz y reportes

Tags: mvc, xml, pdf, odoo

En mi modulo de odoo implemente el modelo para hacer reportes en xml y convertirlos en pdf pero me marca un error cuando desde la interfaz quiero darle algun diseño aparte inclui un encabezado con una imagen y un titulo en  el reporte pero no aparece ni el titulo ni la imagen no se si es como esta distribuida la vista o que sea

Adjunto codigo:

```
'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

```
<record id="action_report_presupuesto" model="ir.actions.report">
    <field name="name">Presupuesto</field>
    <field name="model">presupuesto</field>
    <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
    <field name="report_name">peliculas.report_presupuesto</field>
    <field name="report_file">peliculas.report_presupuesto</field>
    <field name="print_report_name">('Presupuesto - %s' %(object.name))</field>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_presupuesto"/>
    <field name="binding_type">report</field>
</record>

<template id="report_presupuesto">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
      <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
        <t t-call="web.external_layout">
            <div class="page">
                <center>
                    <t t-if="o.state == 'borrador'">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                           EL estado de este presupuesto es Borrador
                        </div>
                    </t>
                    <t t-else="">
                        <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                            EL estado de este presupuesto es Aprobado
                        </div>
                    </t>
                </center>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <img t-attf-src="data:image/*;base64,{{o.image_1920}}" style="max-width:200px"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-9">
                        <h2><span t-field="o.name"/></h2>
                        <ul class="list-inline" style="font-size:20px;">
                            <li t-if="o.Clasificacion">Clasifiacion:<span t-field="o.Clasificacion"/></li>
                            <li t-if="o.fch_estreno">Estreno:<span t-field="o.fch_estreno"/></li>
                            <li t-if="o.genero_ids">Genero:<span t-field="o.genero_ids"/></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="list-inline" style="font-size:20px; padding-top: 30px">
                            <li t-if="o.fch_creacion">Creacion:<span t-field="o.fch_creacion"/></li>
                            <li t-if="o.fch_aprobado">Aprobado:<span t-field="o.fch_aprobado"/></li>
                            <li t-if="o.create_uid">Vendedor:<span t-field="o.create_uid"/></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <table class="table table-sm" style="margin-top:30px;">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Imagen</th>
                        <th>Recurso</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Importe</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <t t-set="ctd_lineas" t-value="0"/>
                        <tr t-foreach="o.detalle_ids" t-as="l">
                            <td><img t-attf-src="data:image/*;base64,{{l.imagen}}" style="max-width:80px"/></td>
                            <td><span t-field="l.name"/></td>
                            <td><span t-field="l.cantidad"/></td>
                            <td><span t-field="l.precio"/></td>
                            <td><span t-field="l.importe"/></td>
                            <t t-set="ctd_lineas" t-value="ctd_lineas+1"/>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div class="row justify-content-end" style="padding-top: 30px;">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <table class="table-sm">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Subtotal</td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><span t-field="o.base"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>Impuestos</td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><span t-field="o.impuestos"/></td>
                                </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>Total</td>
                                    <td class="text-right"><span t-field="o.total"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px">
                    <span>El presente presupuesto cuenta con <t t-esc="ctd_lineas"/> lineas de detalle</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </t>
      </t>
   </t>
</template>
```

'''

el error que muestra en la interfaz n oidentifico bien que sea no se si es del modelo o de la vista

adjunto imagen de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ese es el error que muestra en la terminal no se a que se deba que tendria que hacer para que me deje editarlo y para que la imagen del encabezado se muestre

Comment: Hay un campo que no existe en tu modelo `res.config.settings`,`stock_move_sms_validation`

Comment: eso lo mostro desde que me dijiste que lo desinstalara o lo volviera a instalar

Comment: como puedo corregir eso? @Legna

Comment: Si no estas heredando ese modelo, asegurate que en vez de haber usado `_inherit` hayas usado `_name` en algúno de tus modelos. No deberías tener dos modelos con el mismo `_name`

Comment: solo tengo 3 modelos y en el modelo padre tengo un inherit y dentro de ese tengo esto 'mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin', 'image.mixin'

Comment: estuve revisando y corregi unas cosas pero no funciono @Legna

Comment: Intenta de nuevo reiniciando el server, desinstalando el modulo, etc...